# How to run Chrome Hangout extension even if the chrome is not running?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, google-chrome-devtools, google-hangouts

I want to run the Chrome **Only** Hangout Extension whether the chrome is running or not.

*Link of the Hangout Extension* https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hangouts/nckgahadagoaajjgafhacjanaoiihapd?hl=en

In settings I checked the given below option but its allowing all extensions to run in behind where I want only and only chrome hangout to run in background and nothing else

> Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is Closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't run Hangouts without Chrome as Hangouts is basically web app and needs browser to work. However if you want to make Hangouts independent of the browser you use for browsing web then you can install [Hangouts Chrome App](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-hangouts/knipolnnllmklapflnccelgolnpehhpl?hl=en) which (opposed to [Hangouts Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-hangouts/nckgahadagoaajjgafhacjanaoiihapd?hl=en)) uses its own instance of Chrome behind the scene. The end effect is that Hangouts Chrome App behaves like every other desktop application.

Comment: HC App in Chromium it adds a button inside the browser to start it as a separate window. But I don't find a way to start that window without opening a Chromium window.